# Django generating foreign key relationship based on slug in url

Tags: python, django

First, English isn't my first language, and neither is Django.

Let's say I have the model '*city*' with a parent / foreign key relationship to a '*province*' (each province can have multiple cities in it).

models.py:

```
class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75, help_text="What province are you adding?", unique=True, default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class City(models.Model):
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #Each city belongs to one province
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

A city can be added to a province via a CreateView.

My relevant views.py looks like this:

```
class AddCityView(CreateView):
    model = City
    form_class = CityForm
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('app:provincedetail', kwargs={'slug' : self.object.province.slug})
```

And the relevant urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.ProvinceDetailView.as_view(), name='provincedetail'), #shows province information in more detail
    path('<slug:province>/add/', views.AddCityView.as_view(), name='addcity'), #add a city to a province
]
```

So when a user goes to the province detail view, they can add a city pretty easily from there via a form. I think it would be redundant to have a field for the province in this form, it should just be automatically generated from when the user submits the city form. In my mind, this would be done through the url since the province slug is already in it. What would be the best way to do this?

My idea is to change the field value after the form is submitted by overriding the form_valid function of the CreateView like so:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()
    self.province = #but then how would I pass the slug in the url to this? How do I even get the url in a CreateView function?
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

However, I'm not sure how I can get the current url data in views.py and pass the relevant part (the slug) to self.province. How would I do this? I know you can use {{ request.path }} in template view, but I don't think that would be applicable here.

Any help would be appreciable, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should make your slugs unique, then in your view you can access the slug through `self.kwargs`:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class AddCityView(CreateView):
    model = City
    form_class = CityForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
       city = form.save(commit=False)
       city.province = get_object_or_404(Province, slug=self.kwargs['province'])
       city.save()
       self.object = city
       return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```